# Sharing of memory by cores within a Executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say we have 5 worker machines. Each worker node has configuration of `16 cores` and `64 GB memory`. So Total `80 core` and `320 GB memory`.

Now we can configure the properties as below:

- option-1: set large executor

  - 1 executor per 1 machine, ie. each executor having 63 GB memory and 15 core (removing os/overhead etc)
- option-2: set 5 core per executor

  - number of cores per executors : 5
  - number of executors per machine : 15 core / 5 = 3
  - memory per executor : 63 GB / 3 executor = 21 GB
  - what are the pro and cons of option-1 vs option-2?

Question - for the cases where a executor need high memory (for eg: group by on column having skewed data), irrespective of the approaches chosen above, given cores available in executor share the memory of executor (ie. in option-1 , 15 cores share memory of 63GB, what if a specific core or task needs more memory than 63gb/15), how can we handle such cases in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

**option 1(large executor)** means simpler cluster management, improves data locality as long as the large memory pool can be used efficiently by your tasks.
fewer tasks can be run in parallel(say your spark job reads 100k parquet files - only 4-5 tasks can be done at a time; on the other hand if you have 10 large parquet files to read, this may be a better option)

**option 2(smaller executor)** has better fault tolerance (to restart failed tasks) and can use resources more efficiently.

Dynamic allocation allows Spark to dynamically adjust the number of executors based on workload. You can enable it and set minimum and maximum numbers of executors:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Dynamic Allocation Example") \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", 2) \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", 1) \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", 10) \
    .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Increasing this can be beneficial for tasks requiring significant memory for operations outside the Java heap:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Memory Overhead Example") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "1024") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Custom partitioners can help distribute your data more evenly across partitions. While PySpark doesn't allow creating custom partitioners directly like Scala/Java, you can achieve a similar effect by manipulating your data.
`partitioned_df = df.repartition("key")`

Broadcast variables are used to save a copy of data on all nodes. This can be beneficial when joining a large DataFrame with a small one:

`broadcast_df = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(small_df.collect())`

Now, you can access 'broadcast_df.value' in your operations to use the broadcasted data.

Salting involves adding a random prefix to keys to distribute data more evenly. Here's an example of how you might implement salting in a join operation:

```
large_df = large_df.withColumn("salted_key", F.concat(large_df["key"], F.lit("_"), (F.rand()*10).cast("int")))

salted_small_df = small_df.crossJoin(spark.range(0, 10).withColumnRenamed("id", "salt")).withColumn("salted_key", F.concat(small_df["key"], F.lit("_"), F.col("salt")))

joined_df = large_df.join(salted_small_df, "salted_key")
```

Comment: sorry for responding late. In Option-1, why `fewer tasks can be run in parallel`? is not the number of cores remain same(15) per worker node irrespective of both options-1 or 2? Also why option-2 has `better fault tolerance (to restart failed tasks)` compared to option-1?

Comment: fault tolerance: Imagine a restaurant with 15 chefs (cores).

Option 1: One giant kitchen (executor) - A single kitchen fire (executor failure) shuts down the whole operation.
Option 2: Three smaller kitchens (executors) - A fire in one kitchen (executor failure) only affects that kitchen's orders (tasks), while the others keep running.

Task Size: If your tasks are small, Option 2 will be more beneficial.
Data Size: If your data requires significant memory per task, Option 1 might be suitable, but consider memory overhead.

Comment: thank you Ananth. As far `Task Size` and  `Data Size` you mentioned in the above comment, irrespective of the options we choose between 1 vs 2, is not number cores at worker remains same ie. 15 cores  (may be 15 core/ 1 executor in option-1 and 15 core/3 executor in option-2 so 5 core per executor), but total 15 cores right, if that is the case , then how option1 and 2 help for usecases you mentioned on the comment related to Task Size/Data Size?